# Avoid Type casting on Factory Pattern

Tags: dart, design-patterns, architecture, factory-pattern, solid-principles

I am writing a payment service class in Dart that wraps more than 1 payment provider. The expectation is the caller can simply switch one to another without any hassle.
Let's imagine I have classes like this:

```
enum PaymentProvider { providerA, providerB }

abstract class PaymentService {
   void processPayment(Order oder);
}

class PaymentServiceA implements PaymentService {
    final String appKey;
    final String merchantId;
    
    PaymentServiceA(this.appKey, this.merchantId);


    @override
    void processPayment(Order oder) {
      // concrete implementation to process payment
    }

    String getVoucher() {
       // return voucher code
    }
}

class PaymentServiceB implements PaymentService {
    final PaymentBOptions options;
    
    PaymentServiceB(this.options);


    @override
    void processPayment(Order oder) {
      // concrete implementation to process payment
    }

    List<PaymentBHistory> getPaymentHistory() {
      // return payment history
    }

}

class PaymentBOptions {
   final bool sendEmailReceipt;
   final Function()? successCallback;

   PaymentBOptions(this.sendEmailReceipt, this.successCallback);
}
```

So here PaymentServiceA and PaymentServiceB have same method (processPayment) so we can create base class PaymentService and let them implements this base class.
However as you can see each of them also has different constructor parameter and specific methods.

How is the best approach to create PaymentService that wrap more than 1 provider like this?

I was trying to use factory pattern like this:

```
abstract class PaymentService {
   factory PaymentService(PaymentProvider provider) {
      switch(provider) {
        case PaymentProvider.providerA:
          String appKey = "xxxx";
          String merchantId = "123"
          return PaymentServiceA(appKey, merchantId);
        case PaymentProvider.providerB:
          PaymentBOptions options = PaymentBOptions(() {
              
          });
          return PaymentServiceB(options);        
      }
   }

 
   void processPayment(Order order);
}
```

But I don't think this is the good practice because:

1. If we create PaymentServiceA or PaymentServiceB instance using PaymentService factory method it will return as PaymentService and we need to cast to appropriate class in order to access specific PaymentService method.
2. We can't supply specific constructor parameter of PaymentServiceA or PaymentServiceB outside PaymentService abstract class via factory constructor.

Any idea on how is the best practice and what's the suitable design pattern when facing this kind of scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: Use two static functions on `PaymentService`: `static PaymentServiceA a(PaymentAOptions options) => PaymentServiceA(options);` and ditto for `B`.

Or don't bother, and point people to the subclasses, which they need to be aware of anyway since they have different APIs.

(I'd probably drop the `PaymentProvider` enum entirely. It duplicates the type hierarchy, so it doesn't add anything.)

Comment: Hm, i'm still looking for another opinion because seems having two static function inside PaymentService make PaymentService class kinda pointless.

Comment: You have two different operations, taking different arguments. Trying to shoe-horn that into one function is possible, but not easier to use for anybody. If you have to create a `PaymentBOptions` object anyway, to be able to call that method, you might as well just put a `PaymentB create()` method on the `PaymentBOptions` object and call it `PaymentBBuilder` instead.